# how to minimize the View State Size on Salesforce

Tags: salesforce

I have a issue with View state on Salesforce, need to help:
Salesforce has maximum view state size limit (135KB) exceeded. My website get view state is greater than limited of Salesforce. I am searched on google and getting some solutions but not improve much :(, anyone to help me?, thank you so much!

Jerry

Comment: We can't help much without code.

Answer (score 2):

I have faced this issue many times. If you want to reduce your internal size use HTMl table instead of   Page Block table or Data table.
These page block table (and others apex tables) they apply their own internal validation on table columns and data, so just change every thing to plain html table.
By doing this you might reduced it from 199 to 99 kb. I have done it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure someone can fill in a more complete answer.  But a first step would be to read about the `transient` keyword.  Properties / member variables in the controller marked transient are not saved in the Viewstate.   If you have a bunch of unnecessary stuff in there then this will help.

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_classes_keywords_transient.htm

Comment: Try http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/An_Introduction_to_Visualforce_View_State one too.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I used transient keyword for variables but it does not reduce but increases, so strange. I saw descending order is: Internal, Expressions and Controllers. The Controllers contains small size. have any way to reduce in Internal or Expressions?

Thanks so much!
Jerry

Comment: I also tried transient on everything I could but it increased the view state by nearly double

Answer (score 0):

A good first step would be to look what takes most size of view state. You can see it by enabling development mode in user profile. Few tips and a good introduction is [here](http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/An_Introduction_to_Visualforce_View_State)
Another more advanced useful resource would be this [answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/4537/how-to-reduce-a-large-internal-view-state-what-is-in-the-internal-view-state) (regarding internal part )

Answer (score 0):

Few fixes that might help are

Add transient keyword before variables, like lists used just for printing the tables.

Use HTML components instead of Salesforce components (Mostly if the SF Components are used within apex:repeat). The SF Components consume more view state than the HTML Components. E.g. use a HTML table instead of apex:pageBlockTable.

Hope this helps.

Read more about it on

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_best_practices_performance.htm

http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/An_Introduction_to_Visualforce_View_State